# Get Element that Parent not a class

Tags: javascript, css, xpath, protractor, element

I would like to return an element in javascript that does not have a class in its parent element.

For example, I would like to get the child class element in the following code snippet that **does not have 'parent' as a class** for the parent element:

```
<div>
   <div class= "parent">
      <div class="child">
         Not to be selected 
      </div>
   </div>
   <div>
     <div class="child">
        To be selected
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I tried to return it through xpath in protractor

Comment: *"I would like to get the child class element in the following code snippet..."* There are three such child elements in that markup (two with no class at all, one with `class="child"`). Which one do you want? Or do you mean you just want to look at ones `class="child"` that aren't immediately within `class="parent"`?

Comment: Please provide the JavaScript you have tried.

Comment: Please clarify if JavaScript answers using the DOM are relevant. You mentioned xpath and protractor, but tucked away at the end on a question tagged [tag:javascript].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/:not) selector .

```js
console.log(document.querySelectorAll(':not(.parent) > .child'));
```

```html
<div>
   <div class= "parent">
      <div class="child">
         Not to be selected 
      </div>
   </div>
   <div>
     <div class="child">
        To be selected
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a few ways to do this. Either you check if the class is there.

```
var elementList = [];
document.querySelectorAll("div.child").forEach(function(e) {
  var parent = e.parentElement;
  if(parent.classList == null || !parent.classList.contains("parent")) {

    elementList.push(e);
  }
})
console.log(elementList);
```

If the parent class is specific you can use the css :not attribute

```
var elementList = document.querySelectorAll("div:not(.parent) > div.child");
console.log(elementList);
```